# google play alpha test download issues

Tags: google-play, android-testing

Alpha test download link downloads differents versions of the application to testers. The version number of the downloaded application is the lastest one but it is missing some functionalities that are in the latest version that I published.

So we tried again to download the latest version of the application through the Internal Testing and Internal app sharing of Google play but we are encountering the same issue.

Has anybody encountered the same issue? Can you assist?

Thank you.